# Cocoa : Image Well - Custom NSImageView class doesn't show image?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsimageview

I added an imagewell via interface builder, set an image, then ran and all is well. (the image is displayed).

However, if I change the custom class to one of my own (NSImageView subclass), the image is no longer displayed. This is a bare class with nothing added. Any reason why this wouldn't work?

I then tried to manually set an image in the initWithFrame method:

```
    [self setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [self setImageAlignment:NSImageAlignCenter];

    NSLog(@"image is valid? %@", [[self image] isValid] ? @"yes" : @"no");
```

But this too did not work. No errors, just no image shown.

Any ideas as to what might be my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you call super drawRect inside the drawRect method.

```
 - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
 {
     [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
     // Drawing code here.
 }
```

Comment: Oh of course! I didn't actually need to draw anything custom, so forgot about that. I just needed to add some mouse events. Thank you.

Comment: You might as well delete the method if you don't need it. Event that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bindings again, in XIB, Probably you might need to again link ImageView with your New "SubClassImageView"

hope that should solve the problem....